# XCode: placing cursor at breakpoint location on breakpoint hit

Tags: xcode, cursor, breakpoints

I want to remove several breakpoints along my program execution path. XCode stops at each breakpoint and I want to clear it immediately. In contrast to all other tools that I used to, Xcode does not put cursor on the line it stopped. Therefore, "toggle breakpoint" shortcut instead of clearing current breakpoint, puts breakpoint somewhere out of sight.

To clear current breakpoint I need to grab mouse or press extra shortcut before actually clearing breakpoint. It gets very annoying for several breakpoints in row.

Maybe there's workaround?

Answer (score 0):

You can click inside the topmost thread in the Debug Navigator <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> to see where you stopped.

If you want to automatically skip a breakpoint or perform other actions when it's triggered you can Right-Click or Control+Click the breakpoint, choose `Edit Breakpoint...` then check `Automatically continue after evaluating actions`.